# Events and page loads firing for different Universal analytics property

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, universal-analytics

I created new universal analytics property.
All page load events firing to new universal analytics property but events are firing in old Property. I am using below custom HTML for firing events. My Tracking id in this code UA-XXXXXXX-2 but events are firing in UA-XXXXXX-1(old tracking id)

```
<script type="text/javascript">


(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  var ga = ga || [];
  ga ('create', 'UA-XXXXXXX-2', 'auto');


  $('.tab').eq(0).click(function(){
  ga ('send', 'pageview', '/us/en/technologies/surround-7-1/tab-overviewtest');
  });

  $('.tab').eq(1).click(function(){
  ga ('send', 'pageview', '/us/en/technologies/surround-7-1/tab-hardware and software');
  });

  $('.tab').eq(2).click(function(){
  ga ('send', 'pageview', '/us/en/technologies/surround-7-1/tab-documents');
  });

</script>
```

How to solve this.

Comment: There is no event tracking code in your example, so I rather suspect that you have some old code in some other part of your website.

Comment: This is for virtual Pageviews

Comment: Yes, I gathered. But there is no event tracking in your code, and you said you had a problem with events.

Comment: `var ga = ga || [];` should not be there. Is there any other GA code on the page?

Comment: I think the line
    var ga = ga || [];
should not affect analytics in a negative way. It only verifies that the ga object is defined, and if not then define it. I just verified on my own site this line, and it works fine with it.

Comment: You are confusing this with the gaq-array in "classic" analytics. With Universal Analytics ga is a function, not an array; the reason the line does no harm (does nothing, indeed) is that ga is defined as a function in the Universal Analytics code above, so it is never undefined when you test it.